# how i do solve problem with permision denied

Tags: python-3.x, terminal

hello everyone I'm studying udacity, n they asked me to download python and git bash. I did it , when I start work on terminal I type cd Downloads/ : comes up this ~ like everything is fine. then I type ls which gives all my files and over is greeting.py which I need. next step is python3 greeting.py n that's it : permission denied. I don't know what to do , I tried to add a path to the python.exe, but it didn't work. help me guys plz

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Your question does not meet the minimum requirements of this site at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you are on Windows, based on "tried to add a path to the python.exe".

Notice that the app is python.exe and not python3.exe. On Windows, you may have to replace all python3 commands with python. In your case, I suspect this is the fix.

You should run `python greeting.py` instead of `python3 greeting.py`.